# Lost Background on Wordpress Post Area

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm in need of some serious help. I'm working on a Wordpress website and removed something I shouldn't have, and now I can't get it back, plus, I'm not sure what I deleted. The only page that seems to be affected is the home page, while the rest of the pages are fine.

I was trying to remove a few things from the sidebar, and they're gone now, but the post background is gone (needs to be white), and the footer is pushed to the left side.

I've looked at the page encoding through my browser, and I can identify what div it's in, however, I'm having trouble locating it in my Wordpress files.

Any help is appreciated.

The website is located here: http://mathenyheatcool.com/

Here's the code I was editing (I was working @ the bottom):

```
enter code here
<?php
/*
Template Name: Matheny Home Page
*/
?>



<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div class="post">
<?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>




<div id="matheny-sidebar-block">

<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/contact-us/schedule-service/">
<img src="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/schedule-repair-service.png" alt="Heating and Cooling Repair Service"></a></div>

<br />


<div style="width:100%;text-align:left;">

<?php
$monthname = date("F");
if($monthname == "March" || $monthname == "April" || $monthname == "May"){
echo '<a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><span style="font-size:large;color:#D2691E;">It\'s Time for Spring Maintenance</span></a>';



echo '<br /><strong>Get Your AC Cleaned & Checked</strong><br/><div style="text-align:left;font-size:small;">Preventative maintenance means fewer systems failures and prolongs the life of your heating and cooling equipment and ensures efficient operation. <a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/services/#heating_cooling_maintenance">Planned Maintenance Contracts</a> are available.</div><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><strong>Click Here</a> or call us at 314-727-9000</strong></div><div style="font-size:small;"> to schedule your cooling system maintenance appointment.';
}
elseif($monthname == "September" || $monthname == "October" || $monthname == "November")  {
echo '<a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><span style="font-size:large;color:#D2691E;">It\'s Time for Fall Maintenance</span></a>';


echo '<br /><strong>Get Your Heating Cleaned & Checked</strong><br/><div style="text-align:left;font-size:small;">Preventative maintenance means fewer systems failures and prolongs the life of your heating and cooling equipment and ensures efficient operation. <a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/services/#heating_cooling_maintenance">Planned Maintenance Contracts</a> are available.</div><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><strong>Click Here</a> or call us at 314-727-9000</strong></div><div style="font-size:small;"> to schedule your heating system maintenance appointment.';
}
else{
echo '<a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><span style="font-size:large;color:#D2691E;">Need Regular Maintenance?</span></a>';


echo '<br /><strong>Get Your System Cleaned & Checked</strong><br/><div style="text-align:left;font-size:small;">Preventative maintenance means fewer systems failures and prolongs the life of your heating and cooling equipment and ensures efficient operation. <a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/services/#heating_cooling_maintenance">Planned Maintenance Contracts</a> are available.</div><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-service/"><strong>Click Here</a> or call us at 314-727-9000</strong></div><div style="font-size:small;"> to schedule your heating and cooling system maintenance appointment.';

}
?>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-comfort-consultation/">
<span style="font-size:x-large;color:#707070;">Time for new equipment?</span>
<img src="http://mathenyheatcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/new_air_conditioner.jpg" /></a><br /><strong>Free In-Home Comfort Consultation</strong><br/><div style="text-align:left;font-size:small;">We are an independent American Standard Customer Care dealer specializing in high-efficiency heating and cooling systems.</div><a href="http://www.mathenyheatcool.com/schedule-comfort-consultation/"><strong>Click Here</a> or call us at 314-727-9000</strong></div><div style="font-size:small;"> to schedule your free in-home Comfort Consultation.</div>

 <br /><br />

<br />

</div>




<?php get_sidebar('home1'); ?> 

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Were you removing things from the `sidebar.php` file, or from a widget text area with HTML?

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing a closing `</div>` somewhere. More info on the file(s) you were editing will help.

Comment: I removed a widget in the sidebar by deleting it from the Wordpress menu. The code above is what I edited.

Comment: It 'might' be in inactive widgets. Try there. If not, then you'll need to copy/paste that code into whatever widget you had used previously. Or insert that into the sidebar (but then it's hard coded).

Comment: I added a blank text box to the sidebar and the post background came back. I deleted the last </div> on the code I entered above and the footer moved back to the center.

Comment: On the main page the ``#page`` covers rougly nothing, while on other pages the ``#page`` covers the area it should and the background is fine. I guess the issue with the ``</div>``.